# Pass Grep Results to Variable and Print

Tags: bash

I have few files in directory.
I want to find every user in files.

Lines example:

user user1

user user2

I am trying to execute bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIRECTORY=/files

for file in `ls $DIRECTORY/*; do
        while read row; do
                user=$(grep -oP 'user \s' $row)
                echo "UserName = $user"
        done < $file  
done
```

I want to have result:
UserName = user1;

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Just curious, where did you learn to do `for file in \`ls $DIRECTORY/*\``?

Comment: from guy in my company

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify like that :

`grep -r "user" $DIRECTORY | awk '{print "UserName = "$2}'`

- `grep -r` : Recursively grep all files
- `awk '{print $2}'` : print the 2nd row of the line